# R Kernel is not working with Jupyter notebook

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, anaconda3

I am trying to solve the problem of my Jupyter notebook not being able to run r code in its r kernel because of a disconnection issue.  I am running Jupyter on a Mac with BigSur 11.6 and the notebook opens right until I try to run a cell when the kernel lose the connection and becomes connecting to kernel showing the information below, but it never reconnects:

```
Last login: Wed Oct  6 12:40:11 on ttys001
/opt/anaconda3/envs/entornor/bin/jupyter_mac.command ; exit;                    
(base) fersaol@MacBook-Air-de-fersaol ~ % /opt/anaconda3/envs/entornor/bin/jupyter_mac.command ; exit;
[I 13:33:25.566 NotebookApp] The port 8888 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 13:33:25.567 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /Users/fersaol
[I 13:33:25.567 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.4.3 is running at:
[I 13:33:25.567 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8889/?token=9a9e27f00fcdc90028309fc5676e2548f6cbd2e6acb79550
[I 13:33:25.567 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8889/?token=9a9e27f00fcdc90028309fc5676e2548f6cbd2e6acb79550
[I 13:33:25.567 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 13:33:25.570 NotebookApp] 
    
    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///Users/fersaol/Library/Jupyter/runtime/nbserver-9257-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8889/?token=9a9e27f00fcdc90028309fc5676e2548f6cbd2e6acb79550
     or http://127.0.0.1:8889/?token=9a9e27f00fcdc90028309fc5676e2548f6cbd2e6acb79550
/opt/anaconda3/envs/entornor/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py:257: UserWarning: date_default is deprecated since jupyter_client 7.0.0. Use jupyter_client.jsonutil.json_default.
  return _iterencode(o, 0)
[W 13:33:32.946 NotebookApp] Notebook INSPYR/Curso Data Analytics 2021_2022/R/kernel_R_blank.ipynb is not trusted
ERROR:asyncio:Exception in callback <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7fc5f002d5b0>(<Future finis...late\r\n\r\n'>)
handle: <Handle <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7fc5f002d5b0>(<Future finis...late\r\n\r\n'>)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/entornor/lib/python3.8/asyncio/events.py", line 81, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
RuntimeError: Cannot enter into task <Task pending name='Task-4' coro=<HTTP1ServerConnection._server_request_loop() running at /opt/anaconda3/envs/entornor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/http1connection.py:823> wait_for=<Future finished result=b'GET /kernel...flate\r\n\r\n'> cb=[IOLoop.add_future.<locals>.<lambda>() at /opt/anaconda3/envs/entornor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py:688]> while another task <Task pending name='Task-1' coro=<MultiKernelManager._async_start_kernel() running at /opt/anaconda3/envs/entornor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/multikernelmanager.py:186>> is being executed.
ERROR:asyncio:Exception in callback <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7fc611af0fd0>(<Future finis...uest\r\n\r\n'>)
handle: <Handle <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7fc611af0fd0>(<Future finis...uest\r\n\r\n'>)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/entornor/lib/python3.8/asyncio/events.py", line 81, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
RuntimeError: Cannot enter into task <Task pending name='Task-5' coro=<HTTP1ServerConnection._server_request_loop() running at /opt/anaconda3/envs/entornor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/http1connection.py:823> wait_for=<Future finished result=b'GET /api/co...quest\r\n\r\n'> cb=[IOLoop.add_future.<locals>.<lambda>() at /opt/anaconda3/envs/entornor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py:688]> while another task <Task pending name='Task-2' coro=<KernelManager._async_start_kernel() running at /opt/anaconda3/envs/entornor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py:331>> is being executed.
ERROR:asyncio:Exception in callback <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7fc5f002da60>(<Future finis...late\r\n\r\n'>)
handle: <Handle <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7fc5f002da60>(<Future finis...late\r\n\r\n'>)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/entornor/lib/python3.8/asyncio/events.py", line 81, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
RuntimeError: Cannot enter into task <Task pending name='Task-12' coro=<HTTP1ServerConnection._server_request_loop() running at /opt/anaconda3/envs/entornor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/http1connection.py:823> wait_for=<Future finished result=b'GET /custom...flate\r\n\r\n'> cb=[IOLoop.add_future.<locals>.<lambda>() at /opt/anaconda3/envs/entornor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py:688]> while another task <Task pending name='Task-36' coro=<MappingKernelManager.start_kernel() running at /opt/anaconda3/envs/entornor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/kernelmanager.py:176> cb=[IOLoop.add_future.<locals>.<lambda>() at /opt/anaconda3/envs/entornor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py:688]> is being executed.
ERROR:asyncio:Exception in callback <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7fc5f002d790>(<Future finis...late\r\n\r\n'>)
handle: <Handle <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7fc5f002d790>(<Future finis...late\r\n\r\n'>)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/entornor/lib/python3.8/asyncio/events.py", line 81, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
RuntimeError: Cannot enter into task <Task pending name='Task-13' coro=<HTTP1ServerConnection._server_request_loop() running at /opt/anaconda3/envs/entornor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/http1connection.py:823> wait_for=<Future finished result=b'GET /static...flate\r\n\r\n'> cb=[IOLoop.add_future.<locals>.<lambda>() at /opt/anaconda3/envs/entornor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py:688]> while another task <Task pending name='Task-36' coro=<MappingKernelManager.start_kernel() running at /opt/anaconda3/envs/entornor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/kernelmanager.py:176> cb=[IOLoop.add_future.<locals>.<lambda>() at /opt/anaconda3/envs/entornor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py:688]> is being executed.
[I 13:33:33.022 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 4c13344d-0183-4a69-ae2f-b096e0381969, name: ir
[W 13:33:33.029 NotebookApp] 404 GET /nbextensions/widgets/notebook/js/extension.js?v=20211006133325 (::1) 8.840000ms referer=http://localhost:8889/notebooks/INSPYR/Curso%20Data%20Analytics%202021_2022/R/kernel_R_blank.ipynb
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libreadline.6.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/anaconda3/lib/R/lib/libR.dylib
  Reason: image not found
[I 13:33:36.025 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), new random ports
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libreadline.6.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/anaconda3/lib/R/lib/libR.dylib
  Reason: image not found
[W 13:34:33.048 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from 4c13344d-0183-4a69-ae2f-b096e0381969
[W 13:34:37.607 NotebookApp] Nudge: attempt 10 on kernel 4c13344d-0183-4a69-ae2f-b096e0381969
[W 13:34:42.648 NotebookApp] Nudge: attempt 20 on kernel 4c13344d-0183-4a69-ae2f-b096e0381969
[W 13:34:47.703 NotebookApp] Nudge: attempt 30 on kernel 4c13344d-0183-4a69-ae2f-b096e0381969
[W 13:34:52.761 NotebookApp] Nudge: attempt 40 on kernel 4c13344d-0183-4a69-ae2f-b096e0381969
[W 13:34:57.822 NotebookApp] Nudge: attempt 50 on kernel 4c13344d-0183-4a69-ae2f-b096e0381969
[W 13:35:02.875 NotebookApp] Nudge: attempt 60 on kernel 4c13344d-0183-4a69-ae2f-b096e0381969
[W 13:35:07.927 NotebookApp] Nudge: attempt 70 on kernel 4c13344d-0183-4a69-ae2f-b096e0381969
[W 13:35:12.986 NotebookApp] Nudge: attempt 80 on kernel 4c13344d-0183-4a69-ae2f-b096e0381969
[W 13:35:18.039 NotebookApp] Nudge: attempt 90 on kernel 4c13344d-0183-4a69-ae2f-b096e0381969
[W 13:35:23.096 NotebookApp] Nudge: attempt 100 on kernel 4c13344d-0183-4a69-ae2f-b096e0381969
[W 13:35:28.146 NotebookApp] Nudge: attempt 110 on kernel 4c13344d-0183-4a69-ae2f-b096e0381969
/opt/anaconda3/envs/entornor/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py:257: UserWarning: date_default is deprecated since jupyter_client 7.0.0. Use jupyter_client.jsonutil.json_default.
  return _iterencode(o, 0)
[I 13:35:33.001 NotebookApp] Saving file at /INSPYR/Curso Data Analytics 2021_2022/R/kernel_R_blank.ipynb
[E 13:35:33.058 NotebookApp] Uncaught exception GET /api/kernels/4c13344d-0183-4a69-ae2f-b096e0381969/channels?session_id=a668eb1aa6fd463ea8422ed32d825314 (::1)
    HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8889', method='GET', uri='/api/kernels/4c13344d-0183-4a69-ae2f-b096e0381969/channels?session_id=a668eb1aa6fd463ea8422ed32d825314', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='::1')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/entornor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 956, in _accept_connection
        await open_result
      File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/entornor/lib/python3.8/asyncio/tasks.py", line 349, in __wakeup
        future.result()
    tornado.util.TimeoutError: Timeout
[W 13:35:34.076 NotebookApp] Replacing stale connection: 4c13344d-0183-4a69-ae2f-b096e0381969:a668eb1aa6fd463ea8422ed32d825314
```

Answer (score -1):

- You can use [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks) instead which spins up Jupyter notebook as well
- You can put Jupyter and R into a [docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/r-notebook) to isolate it from your system to minimize errors
- You can try a fresh python env (Seems that the package `asyncio` is broken)

Comment: Thank you very much for your response danlooo, I have to keep using anaconda because of a course I have enrolled to. I just created a new R environment inside anaconda today so Would it be possible to repair that asyncio package? I created another two environments in an old installation of anaconda and did not work as well so I uninstalled anaconda I created a new r environment but the problem is still the same as before.

Comment: Usually, you have one env for R kernel and another one for jupyter. It is almost impossible to reproduce your error.... Do you have the same error using a python kernel instead?

Comment: using python everything works well

Comment: It's a known issue to have trouble with conda envs in which cran an conda r packages are mixed. Try to install the IRkernel package on a R session without conda.

Comment: thank you very much, I am going to try and I will let you know what happened.